# does not update the width and height in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

When I insert records with `jQuery("#table").append(..)` in a table, taking the height and width of the table `jQuery("#table").width()` or `jQuery("#table").height()`, is not updated. If before taking that write "alert('something');", it works well.

Comment: I've seen this happen before where when you insert a debuging alert your code works and then you take it out and it doesn't. Can you post an actual snippet of your code...would be easier for, at least me, to help you.

Comment: You might be inserting invalid HTML, causing something to break or return invalid results. Can you post the exact append statement you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable, here is the problem

```
-moz-binding: url('./assets/xml/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
```

Code for file: "ellipsis.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <binding id="ellipsis">
        <content>
            <xul:window>
                <xul:description crop="end" xbl:inherits="value=xbl:text"><children/></xul:description>
            </xul:window>
        </content>
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

Building the example I did not include the file and there I could see the problem.

thanks